# Получение пользователя через фасад Auth в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, auth, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

В файле `web.php` есть код:

```
Route::get('/user', function() {
    return Auth::user();
});
```

Он возвращает мне пользователя.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но при попытке вставить тот же код в файл `api.php`
Мне не возвращается ничего.
С чем это может быть связано? Заранее спасибо за ответ!
Код в файлах `api.php` и `web.php`: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Но при попытке вставить тот же код в файл api.php` покажите что куда вставляли

Comment: @InDevX обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

После перемещения в аpi.php вам нужно смотреть результат по `http://your.site/api/user`